# Why isn't my program showing the correct results?

Tags: python, list, function

My program is designed to let the user type in temperatures for a whole month. Then I've created functions that are supposed to let the user know a certain temperature for a day by typing in a requested date to see waht temperature he/she typed in for that day. Then there's funktions written to show an average temoerature, the lowest and the highest temperature (by finding these values from a list, where the user typed in the temperatures).

The programming isn't working that well, it answers the user without crashing but it doesn't show the right results. It "skips" to show the requested date, and prints out the whole list when the user asks for highest/lowest temperatures. When I try to get the average value, it crashes with the messange:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Linnea\Documents\Studier\HT 2014\Introduktion till     programmering\Linnea_Andersson.py", line 58, in <module>
main ()
File "C:\Users\Linnea\Documents\Studier\HT 2014\Introduktion till programmering\Linnea_Andersson.py", line 9, in main
functions(temp_list)
File "C:\Users\Linnea\Documents\Studier\HT 2014\Introduktion till programmering\Linnea_Andersson.py", line 53, in functions
print("Average temperature was: " + str(sum(temp_list)/float(len(temp_list),     str(round(total,2)))))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

This is my code:

```
def main ():
    temp_list = create_temp_list()
    search()
    functions(temp_list)

def create_temp_list ():
    NUM_DAYS = 31
    temp_list = [];
    temperatur = [0] * NUM_DAYS
    index = 0
    print("Hi! Type in a temperature for each day in december!: ")
    while index < NUM_DAYS:
        print(index + 1, "/12", ": ", sep="", end="")
        temperatur[index] = float(input())
        index +=1
        temp_list.append(temperatur)
    return temp_list

def search():
    temp_list = [1-31]
    index = int(input("Vänligen skriv in en dag då du vill se temperaturen för: "))
    while (index >= 1 and index < len(temp_list)):
        print("The temperature this day was : ",(temp_list([index - 1])))
    else:
        print ("Ok")
    x = [1,2,3]
    try:
        x[10]
    except IndexError:
       print("What are you trying to pull?")

def functions(temp_list):
    svar1 =(input("To see the highest value, print 'ja': "))
    if svar1 == "ja":
        print("The highest temperature was: ", str(max(temp_list)))
    else:
        print ("This date wasn't found! You are now going to the next function.")
    svar2 = (input("Too see the lowest temperature, print 'ja': "))

    if svar2 == "ja":  
            print("Lowest temperature: ", str(min(temp_list)))
    else:
            print("This date wasn't found! You are now going to the next function.")
    nyfiken = (input("To get the average temperature, print 'ja': "))
    if nyfiken == "ja":
        print("Average temperature was: " + str(sum(temp_list)/float(len(temp_list),         str(round(total,2)))))
    else:
        print("This date wasn't found! The program is now closing.")

#Funktionen skriver ut medelsnittsvärdet
main ()
```

Could anybody help me??

Answer (score 0):

```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'*`
```

You trying to summation between *int* and *list*. Make a for loop on lists first, access the every element of them, then you can make summation.

```
if nyfiken == "ja":
        print("Average temperature was: " + str(sum(temp_list)/float(len(temp_list),str(round(total,2)))))
```

Problem is here, as I said make a *for* loop on *temp_list* and access every element, then make summation.

> Also you converting them to *string*, I dont think you can make summation with strings. You will get an output like :

```
>>> a=10
>>> b=20
>>> str(a)+str(b)
'1020'
>>>
```

Besides you can sum values by following this way:

```
sum1=0
timer=0
y=int(input("How much values do you want to sum?: "))
while True:
    x=int(input("Entry values: "))
    timer+=1
    sum1+=x #sum1=0, we summing every value with eachother. 0 is ineffective value in summation.
    if timer==y:
        print ("Summation of your values: ",sum1)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems; we will approach them in order:

1. `create_temp_list` is supposed to return a list of float - but because of the way you use `temp_list` and `temperatur` and the way Python handles object assignment, it is actually returning a list of references to a list of float, ie `temp_list[0] == temp_list[1] == temp_list[2] ... == temperatur`.  Instead, try

   ```
   NUM_DAYS = 31

   def get_float(prompt):
       while True:
           try:
               return float(input(prompt))
           except ValueError:
               pass

   def create_temp_list():
       print("Hi! Type in a temperature for each day in december!: ")
       make_prompt = "{}/12: ".format
       return [get_float(make_prompt(day)) for day in range(1, NUM_DAYS+1)]
   ```
2. You never pass `temp_list` to `search()`; your program should look more like

   ```
   def main():
       temp_list = create_temp_list()
       search(temp_list)    # <= pass the data to search!
       functions(temp_list)

   def search(temp_list):
       ...
   ```
3. Because of (2), `temp_list` is not in scope (you cannot see that variable in `search`). To fix this, you tried to make test data like `temp_list = [1-31]`. This doesn't do what you think; it makes a one-item list containing the value `-30`. Then `len(temp_list)` is always `1`, and `index >= 1 and index < len(temp_list)` is always `False` - which is good, because otherwise you would be stuck in an endless `while` loop! (It should be `if ... else`, not `while ... else`).

Hope that helps.